# Synonyms for あっち行け

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking for something to say when people try to give money for a bill or try to help in some certain situations, etc.

In English we might say something like

> get out of here

In Chinese I like to say

> 走开、滚蛋、爬开

Unfortunately it doesn't seem like 滚 translates directly into Japanese.

I learned あっち行け but I was wondering if there were any helpful synonyms, rude or not.

Comment: Using 'get out of here' to refuse (voluntary) payment evokes the image of Al Pacino for me. It seems to be a US expression. あっち行け is closer to 'get away from me' and has nothing to do with refusing anything AFAIK.

Comment: `when people try to give money for a bill or try to help` <- そういう場合、普通は「いいからいいから！」「いいっていいって！」「構わん構わん！」「だいじょうぶだいじょうぶ！」「気にすんな！」とか言うんじゃないですかね・・・？ それとも、「だめだめ(、そんなことしちゃ！)」とか・・・？In Japanese, we don't say あっち行け, 失せろ, 消えろ, どけ, じゃまだ etc. in that situation. We use these phrases to literally mean "Go away" "Get away from me" "Get lost" "Get out of my sight" "F**k off".

Comment: @chocolate any different suggestions then?

Comment: えっ、you mean, you want different suggestions other than「いいからいいから」「いいっていいって」「構わん構わん」「大丈夫大丈夫」「気にすんな」「だめだめ」?

Comment: I don't quite get the situation... "when people try to give money for a bill or try to help in some certain situations" ?? Who are the "people" ? FYI, "あっち行け" is a _very_ strong phase if you're not a 10 yrs old boy, perhaps second only to "I'll call police."

Comment: Interesting question. I think I usually say でていけ or 消えろ！ in Japanese and 滾啦 in Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

> detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1497136154 --
>   ‎2012年 ... （より罵倒していますか） ”走开”は普通に「どく」という意味もあります。 ... どけ」という意味に用いる場合は　”你给我走开!”　”走开!”と語調を強めます。 それに対して”滚开”は それだけで「どけ！」という意味になります。 最高レベルの「どけ！」は”滚蛋!

(I think the English word "synonym" is used for individual words only, not for multi-word expressions. I guess those three Chinese 2-character expressions are words or like words.)

「どけ！」　「どいて下さい。」　「さあ、どいて」　「ハイ、どいて」　のけ！　そこのけ！

あっち行け　　失せろ！　　じゃまだ。　立ち去れ。　消えろ！　　解散せよ。　散れ！

消えうせろ。　　直ちに立ち去れ。　　　（Get out!）とっとと出て行け。

With the exception of maybe 「どいて下さい。」「さあ、どいて」「ハイ、どいて」　
I've almost never used or heard any of these expressions in real life.  -- I see them mostly in manga, movies, etc.

Apparently some anime theme song:  <sub>グリーンマンが相手だぞ. (※) 俺の目を見ろ アイビーム · 俺の声聞け マウスビーム. 胸を 開けば 必殺ブレスター. どけ どけ どけ どけ どけ. 失せろ! 見ていろ魔王 手下ども. 
根こそぎ悪を滅ぼすぞ. 子供は誰も渡さない. グリーンマンが挑戦だ.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are trying to achieve あっち行け would be a hilariously rude and confusing thing to say in such a situation.

There's no direct translation for "get out of here" in that context, and even an actual translation of "don't mess/joke about this (I've got the bill)" (ふざけないで) probably is a bit strong for most Japanese people in this duration.

Something like いやいや、いいよ, or いいよ、俺/僕/私が払うから would let them know your intent to pay for them. You will likely have to insist once or twice.

The etiquette around this is not simple and varies between situations; if you're not sure, ask a native and explain the specific situation before-hand. My advice should be fine between friends in most situations though.